# Easiest way to duplicate rows in a table, subtable, and subsubtable

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I am implementing a "Save As Copy" function for a small web app that uses MySQL.

Let's say I have three tables, like so...

```
TABLE Doc
 ID,
 title,
 text

TABLE DocAttributes
 ID,
 DocID -> Doc(ID)
 title,
 text

TABLE DocSubAttributes
 DocAttrID -> DocAttributes(ID)
 title,
 text
```

What we have here is a situation where a single Document can have multiple DocAttributes, and each DocAttribute can in turn have multiple SubAttributes.

Now, if I did not have to worry about the DocSubAttributes table, this would be fairly straightforward, and I would do something like this...

```
$insertID = INSERT INTO Doc (title, text) SELECT title, text FROM Doc WHERE ID = $docID;

INSERT INTO DocAttributes DocID, title, text SELECT $insertID AS DocID, title, text FROM Doc WHERE ID = $docID;
```

However, because there is a third one-to-many table, this method doesn't work. I need to know the primary keys for each DocAttributes row for creating the corresponding rows in  DocSubAttributes.

The only way I am aware of to do this is to iterate through DocAttributes one row at a time, selecting all DocSubAttributes with each iteration, and then doing each insert, again one at a time, iteratively.

I am wondering: Is there a simpler way to duplicate these rows in their respective tables to create an entirely new and separate data entity without relying on iteration?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add ID fields to your tables that link back to the master record, you should be able to accomplish it with three `INSERT` queries (the last of which would have a JOIN to get the new ID).

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own primary key before inserting like, for example,

```
$uniqueKey = md5($ID . $title . $text);
```

And insert that as `DocAttributes` primary key (ID) which you'll now know and use for inserting `DocSubAttributes`